# Regex negative look behind isn't working as expected

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

In python I used this regex

```
(?<!\d\d\d)(\s?lt\.?\s?blue)
```

on this string

```
ltblue
500lt.blue
4009 lt blue
lt. blue
032 lt red
```

I expected it to capture this

```
ltblue
lt. blue
```

but instead it captured

```
ltblue
lt. blue
lt blue
```

From how I wrote it I don't think it should have captured the 'lt blue' after 4009, but for some reason the \s? before 'lt' doesnt seem to work, anyone know how I could change the regex to get the expected output?

Comment: Do the numbers always appear at the start of the lines or is there anything else before numbers in any line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex will try to match your pattern by all means so if `\s` is optional, it will try with and without and keep the one matching. In the case of `4009 lt blue` it matches if there is **no** space in the group (the space is *before* the group, fooling your lookbehind).

Since lookbehinds must have fixed width in python, you cannot add `\s?` to your negative lookbehind but you can still handle this case in another one:

```
(?<!\d{3})(?<!\d{3}\s)(lt\.?\s?blue)
```

Comment: You must have meant [`(?<!\d{3}\s)(?<!\d{3})lt\.?\s?blue`](https://regex101.com/r/bUDzEG/1).

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers always appear at the beginning of the string and there is nothing before the numbers in any line then you can use this: `^(?![\d ]+)(lt[ .]*blue)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sR18Rz/1

The reason why your pattern matched '4009 lt blue' is because, before the l, the `\s?` matched a whitespace zero times and 'l' is not preceded by three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use the [Pypi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) adding an optional `\s?` to the lookbehind, and you can omit the capture group for a match only.

```
import regex as re

pattern = r"(?<!\d\d\d\s?)lt\.?\s?blue\b"

s = ("ltblue\n"
"500lt.blue\n"
"4009 lt blue\n"
"lt. blue\n"
"032 lt red")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rFiaur/1) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##RU7LCgIhFN37FTdXCiHS1CJo8EfcOGgl3JzheoP6erMhJs7mvOCc5c33uQyt5ccyEwOlW3pBqJ0IsQTmRAVGIKncZefjiuo0sjeukwmfyU9SiNpLSiKvRpFCnqxFNps8WnsGZNiMHv6FHQ7fkFKUus9SLqwomWsuMSCq3489VK1b@wA).

Output

```
['ltblue', 'lt. blue']
```